# Getting an error saying my resource route is not defined

Tags: laravel

Error: Route [tasks] not defined.

I created a resource route for my TasksController. I feel like I have done everything I needed to do, but still getting this error. It even shows up correctly when I try get a route list through the terminal.

I tried removing the slash, changing the controller name, changing the route name, but to no avail. I cant think of what else to try. The code was copied from another route and controller that I was using to manage projects.

Lastly, I also double checked the view path everything checks out.

```
Route::resource('/tasks', 'TasksController');
```

Also here is the code for my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tasks;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = Tasks::all();
        return view('tasks/tasks', compact('tasks'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? Seems like you're calling `route('tasks')` somewhere.

Comment: Your awesome! That was exactly the issue. I was just calling route('tasks') in a menu link.

Comment: better to replace this line `Route::resource('/tasks', 'TasksController');` with something that says the route name.. add something like `->name('task');` so that you can properly name that route.

Comment: @BagusTesa Route names are created when using resource controllers. You can see them when running `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: ah right, sorry.